# EDITED : How to change the values from different tables in one sheet to to another one

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to change values in another sheet depending on the value in a specific range.
Whenever cells in firstsheet changes, this whole range gets increased by that percentage

Sheet 2

| A | W | AH | AJ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 | 20 | 11 |
| DEF | 150 | 0 | 10 |
| GHI | 2 | 50 | 15 |

Sheet 1

| A | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gen | 10% | 10% |
| ABC | 5% | 15% |

and so on
General increase : C1 changes B and C column, D2 changes D column

Specific increase :
C2 can be changed for a specific customer eg ABC, which increases B col and C col
D2 can be changed for a specific customer eg ABC, which increases D col
This is working for the range C2, D2 but I need to make a check with row A which has customer name to increase just that customer.

```
Private Sub IncreaseRange(ByVal oMultiplier As Double, ByRef oTarget As Range)
    Dim oValue As Variant
    For Each oValue In oTarget
        oValue.Value = oValue.Value * (1 + oMultiplier)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$C$2"
            Call IncreaseRange(Target.Value, Sheets("Monthly_Budget").Range("W2:AH" & LastRow))
        Case "$D$2"
            Call IncreaseRange(Target.Value, Sheets("Monthly_Budget").Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow))
       
    End Select
        
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Monthly_Budget sheet, what column is the customer name in?

Comment: Your code currently only does something if C2 or D2 is changed. It looks like nothing would happen if C1 or D3 was changed. Do you want the specific increases to happen when you change C2 & D2? Or when you change C3 & D3?

Comment: Hi Edited for clarity, customer names starts from A2 in both sheets

Comment: Still not clear. Which part of your explanation indicates what is currently happening? Which part of your explanation indicates what you want to happen? Again, looking at your code, and copying to my own file, changing C1 currently does nothing. So what do you mean by "C1 changes B and C column"?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `target` can be multiple cells so you should first check that the range that has changed intersects with the range you are interested in. By using the dollar notation in `$C$2"` you are *only* checking cell C2.

Once you have established that the cell being changed is in the right column you need to step through all of the target cells, establish which row it is on, get the value from column A (the name) then look up that name in the other sheet. E.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        'N.B. Disabling events is essential if you are changing values in this same sheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range, fnd As Range
        'Step through all changed cells
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C"))
            Dim nameToFind As String
            nameToFind = Me.Range("A" & CStr(t.Row)).Value
            Set fnd = Sheet2.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=nameToFind, After:=Sheet2.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
                :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
                :=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print t.Row, nameToFind, t.Value, fnd.Address
            Else
                'Could not find that name
            End If
        Next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Couple of points to note - I've disabled events in case I change something on this sheet - you really don't want to get into recursively calling Worksheet_Change. The `On Error GoTo` hopefully ensures that events get turned back on.
Also note the `If Not fnd Is Nothing` in case the name doesn't exist in column A of the other sheet